# SPLToken u64 is not working anymore?

Tags: spl-token

```
let response = await connection.getTokenAccountsByOwner(wallet.publicKey, {"mint": new PublicKey("Mint token")})
response.value.forEach((e) => {
     console.log(`pubkey: ${e.pubkey.toBase58()}`);
     const accountInfo = SPLToken.AccountLayout.decode(e.account.data);
     console.log(`mint: ${new PublicKey(accountInfo.mint)}`);
     console.log(`amount: ${SPLToken.u64.fromBuffer(accountInfo.amount)}`);
              });
```

having an error with this one
**${SPLToken.u64.fromBuffer(accountInfo.amount)}`);**

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fromBuffer')

Comment: Please provide some more context.

Answer (score 1):

You can see here https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/ that the function

```
Token.getAccountInfo
```

does not exists anymore as of version 0.2.0

You will want to use this instead:

```
import { getAccount } from '@solana/spl-token';

const parsedTokenAccountInfo = await getAccount(connection, tokenAccount);
```

which will result in this output:

```
tokenAccountInfo {
  address: PublicKey [PublicKey(7iFn7U1uPWwe4z47v3fP28Mc5F9pqmgYrz9UsjdtzvAj)] {
    _bn: <BN: 63b7a4dec1368066ff069b2a1e84d584dfde9d7a6ea7a520e4945352abef4cc0>
  },
  mint: PublicKey [PublicKey(GiyzqXQUeQr3HZcF9W7a4pDGGbj6qsqxcAKmkFH75tXY)] {
    _bn: <BN: e9a0906181e586a3ad825d611c6e92e4fabb5d5152cdbd8a4f3d52dbd9cc1d17>
  },
  owner: PublicKey [PublicKey(5vJwnLeyjV8uNJSp1zn7VLW8GwiQbcsQbGaVSwRmkE4r)] {
    _bn: <BN: 4916d20d019fe32a08c4facde04ed651a95b3798ed738891df27f4e610cbe02b>
  },
  amount: 5000000000n,
  delegate: null,
  delegatedAmount: 0n,
  isInitialized: true,
  isFrozen: false,
  isNative: false,
  rentExemptReserve: null,
  closeAuthority: null,
  tlvData: <Buffer 07 00 00 00>
}
```

For your specific case you can now use:

```
import { AccountLayout } from "@solana/spl-token";

let response = await connection.getTokenAccountsByOwner(wallet.publicKey, {"mint": mintkeyPair.publicKey})
    response.value.forEach((e) => {
        console.log(`pubkey: ${e.pubkey.toBase58()}`);
        const accountInfo = AccountLayout.decode(e.account.data);
        console.log(`amount: ${accountInfo.amount}`);
});
```

Comment: thanks I need to convert accountInfo.amount to number

Comment: I have just called getTokenAccountsByOwner via http request.